# MySql and Docker com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, spring, docker, liquibase

I want to put my spring rest api with database in mysql in Docker.
application.properties file:

```
server.port=8082
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database:8083/schoolregistrationsystem
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pwd

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/dbchangelog.xml
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

Next I created docker-compose.yml file in directory with project:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  api:
    build: ./SchoolRegistrationSystem
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    depends_on:
      - database
  database:
    container_name: "mysql"
    image: mysql:8
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: schoolregistrationsystem
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pwd
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 8083
    healthcheck:
      test: "/usr/bin/mysql --user=user --password=pwd --execute \"SHOW DATABASES;\""
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 15
    ports:
      - "8083:3306"
```

And next when I am running docker-compose up in power shell I am getting failure.
I have 2 containers: mysql - with status "running" and api with status "exited".

Logs from docker:
EDIT: Full logs from docker

```
2022-07-18 14:09:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.29-1.el8 started.
2022-07-18 14:09:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-07-18 14:09:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.29-1.el8 started.
2022-07-18 14:09:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2022-07-18 14:10:00+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
2022-07-18 14:10:00+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
2022-07-18 14:10:00+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-07-18 14:10:03+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database schoolregistrationsystem
2022-07-18 14:10:03+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user user
2022-07-18 14:10:03+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user user access to schema schoolregistrationsystem

2022-07-18 14:10:03+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
2022-07-18 14:10:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped

2022-07-18 14:10:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.

2022-07-18T14:09:53.062484Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.29) initializing of server in progress as process 42
2022-07-18T14:09:53.069610Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-07-18T14:09:53.547572Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-07-18T14:09:54.932915Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2022-07-18T14:10:00.436541Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.29) starting as process 97
2022-07-18T14:10:00.448283Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-07-18T14:10:00.610010Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-07-18T14:10:00.862119Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-07-18T14:10:00.862179Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2022-07-18T14:10:00.866036Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2022-07-18T14:10:00.912594Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2022-07-18T14:10:00.912814Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.29'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leapseconds' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/tzdata.zi' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2022-07-18T14:10:03.489315Z 9 [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin sha256_password reported: ''sha256_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use caching_sha2_password instead'
2022-07-18T14:10:03.622492Z 14 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.29).
2022-07-18T14:10:04.566088Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.29)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-07-18T14:10:04.808842Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.29) starting as process 1
2022-07-18T14:10:04.814632Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-07-18T14:10:04.919826Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-07-18T14:10:05.104905Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-07-18T14:10:05.104952Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2022-07-18T14:10:05.107347Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2022-07-18T14:10:05.122300Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2022-07-18T14:10:05.122383Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.29'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 8083  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

And I will add logs from Api

```
om.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at     com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
    at     com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar!/:8.0.29]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:266) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21].....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should add a health check for `database` container before starting `api` container. add the following lines to `database` service in `docker-compose.yml` and try again.

```
environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=schoolregistrationsystem
  - MYSQL_USER=user
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pwd
  - MYSQL_TCP_PORT=8083
healthcheck:
      test: "/usr/bin/mysql --user=user --password=pwd --execute \"SHOW DATABASES;\""
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 100
```

Comment: Nothing change. In log of mysql i see something like: 2022-07-18 12:49:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database schoolregistrationsystem            
2022-07-18 12:49:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user user             
2022-07-18 12:49:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user user access to schema schoolregistrationsystem            

2022-07-18 12:49:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
2022-07-18 12:49:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped

2022-07-18 12:49:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.

Comment: @Lulex97 can you update the question with all docker-compose logs from mysql?

Comment: yes, sure. I updated question.

Comment: @Lulex97 can you update the `spring.datasource.username=root` and
`spring.datasource.password=root` with `user` and `pwd` ?

Comment: Ye, I updated it but nothing change :/ I did not think I would get a headache from Docker xd

Comment: @Lulex97 it is odd, in my PC everything works fine, could you destroy all containers with `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)` and repeat the test?

Comment: I do not know what is going on... i deleted even all docker files and nothing change. In api logs i see something like "Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource" - can it has an impact on that problems?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts and time. I restarted my PC and everything works D:

Comment: @Lulex97 I wanted to ask you restart your PC as the last resort :))

Answer (score 0):

Mysql by default runs on Port 3306

So you must use this port in the docker compose file and map it to 8083.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  api:
    build: ./SchoolRegistrationSystem
    ports:
    - "8082:8082"
    depends_on:
      - database
  database:
    container_name: "mysql"
    image: mysql:8
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: schoolregistrationsystem
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
    - "8083:3306"
```

I would also recommend exposing it 3306 as not to confuse others.